# incrementing all values in resourse file by using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a rc file that i increment every nightly build using vbscript, i increment the FILEVERSION and the PRODUCTVERSION, but i can't manage to increment all the values of keywords.
the build is with VS2012.

this is the rc file :

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Hebrew (Israel) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_HEB)
LANGUAGE LANG_HEBREW, SUBLANG_DEFAULT
#pragma code_page(1255)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 3,0,0,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,0,0
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x17L
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040004b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", "SHSAppli Dynamic Link Library"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.0.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "SHSAppli"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2011"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "SHSAppli.dll"
            VALUE "ProductName", "SHSAppli Dynamic Link Library"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.0.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x400, 1200
    END
END

#endif    // Hebrew (Israel) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

and this is script :

```
rcfile = "C:\Build\VS2012Build\SHClientServer\SHSApplicationDLL\SHSApplicationDLL.rc"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set re  = New RegExp
re.Global = True

Function IncMaint(m, g1, g2, g3, pos, src)
  IncMaint = g1 & (Int(g2)+1) & g3
End Function

rctext = fso.OpenTextFile(rcfile).ReadAll

re.Pattern = "((?:PRODUCTVERSION|FILEVERSION) \d+,\d+,)(\d+)(,\d+)"
rctext = re.Replace(rctext, GetRef("IncMaint"))

re.Pattern = "(""(?:ProductVersion|FileVersion)"", ""\d+, \d+, )(\d+)(, \d+"")"
rctext = re.Replace(rctext, GetRef("IncMaint"))

fso.OpenTextFile(rcfile, 2).Write rctext
```

i need to increment also the values "VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.0.0" and   VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.0.0"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if you really should do it - aren't those .rc files UTF8 encoded? But if you must, let the second pattern reflect the fact, that the numbers are separated by "." (dots), not ";" (commas), and be carefull with spaces.

```
"(""(?:ProductVersion|FileVersion)"", ""\d+, \d+, )(\d+)(, \d+"")"
                                           ^    ^^       ^^
```

**Update wrt comment:**

After fixing the second pattern and putting a diagostic line into the replace function, I get this output for a **simplified ascii encoded** file:

```
cscript 22130287.vbs
I'M PLAIN ASCII OR ELSE

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 3,0,0,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,0,0

BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040004b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", "SHSAppli Dynamic Link Library"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.0.0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.0.0"
        END

-----------------
*** FILEVERSION 3,0,|0|,0
*** PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,|0|,0
*** "FileVersion", "3.0.|0|.0"
*** "ProductVersion", "3.0.|0|.0"
I'M PLAIN ASCII OR ELSE

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION 3,0,1,0
 PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,1,0

BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040004b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription", "SHSAppli Dynamic Link Library"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "3.0.1.0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "3.0.1.0"
        END
```

**Update II: The script I use:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sAll : sAll     = goFS.OpenTextFile("22130287.rc").ReadAll()
WScript.Echo sAll
WScript.Echo "-----------------"

Dim re : Set re  = New RegExp
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

re.Pattern = "((?:PRODUCTVERSION|FILEVERSION) \d+,\d+,)(\d+)(,\d+)"
sAll = re.Replace(sAll, GetRef("IncMaint"))

re.Pattern = "(""(?:ProductVersion|FileVersion)"", ""\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)(\.\d+"")"
sAll = re.Replace(sAll, GetRef("IncMaint"))

WScript.Echo sAll
WScript.Quit 0

Function IncMaint(m, g1, g2, g3, pos, src)
  WScript.Echo "***", Join(Array(g1, g2, g3), "|")
  IncMaint = g1 & (Int(g2)+1) & g3
End Function
```

**Update III:**

Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19905469/603855) too.

Comment: @Ekkehard It shouldn't matter how the file is encoded, right? Once he reads the file into VBScript with `OpenTextFile` and `ReadAll`, it's going to be a Unicode string. And `RegExp` operates on Unicode strings natively.

Comment: @Bond - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396199/vbs-script-attempting-to-write-to-rc-file-returns-error for evidence that it does matter.

Comment: can you add the script you run ? i can't reproduce it on my end

Comment: Newton, did you make sure to escape the dots?

Comment: I see the output, but this is not incremented

Comment: @Newton - please clean your glasses: "ProductVersion", "3.0.1.0"; PRODUCTVERSION 3,0,1,0

Comment: thank you, just saw the problem. thank you very much